# Where can I find logs for Bluetooth tablet failure?

Tags: bluetooth, log, tablet, wacom

I occasionally use an Intuos BT M drawing tablet. In the past month it has started misbehaving only on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installation. (It continues to works fine in Windows.)

After making the Bluetooth connection, the tablet works. After 30-60 seconds the screen freezes and the cursor no longer moves. I am forced to restart the machine. This happens when no other applications are running.

To debug this I should probably first look at device-specific logs. Where can I find them?

Comment: See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs

Comment: Here's how to see the system logs: Disconnect the tablet. Put a pin in the timestream `date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp`. Connect the tablet, wait until it fails. Then, `sudo journalctl --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"` will show you logs.

Comment: looks promising https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/wiki/Troubleshooting